# Всплывающее окно python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на этой картинке, при вводе (не отправке) текста, сразу же появляется окно с подсказками. С ними можно взаимодействовать: листать, нажимать. Как называется такой объект? Буду сильно благодарен, если скинете ссылку на документацию.

Comment: режим называется `inline mode` \ `инлайн-режим`

Comment: @ZxNuClear люблю тебя! Спасибо огромное